# Is there a way to make Allah fulfill my wishes to stop being bullied?

Tags: salat

Recently, I have been having a very hard time. Everything is going wrong and nothing is right. I pray at least 4 times a day, but my wishes for a better life are not fulfilled.  I am continuously being bullied, and I pray that it does not happen to me anymore. Is there any special way that will make Allah fulfill my wishes?

Comment: How old are you and where do you live? This is actually (in my opinion) an off-topic question. You say your wishes for a better life is not fullfilled? How do you define a better life? And what steps do you yourself take to try to fullfill that wish?

Comment: In Islam, you would normally pray to have God help you in difficult times with the understanding that this life is a test. As part of that test, sometimes we face such difficulties. So, try to seek practical ways to get yourself out of it if possible. Seek help if you can. Our prayers are usually answered through material means. If you can talk to someone about bullying or discuss the matter with a professional at work or school, please do that. It is important for your health and your future. And perhaps that's what God wants you to do and that's how He will help you and reward you.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you the following:

1. First be sure you are not associating somebody with God, to say, make sure you don't pray/invoke somebody else beside God, otherwise your prayer (salat) will be in vain since you will be not living as muslim but as Mushrik.

Have a look at this verse:
"Allah hath promised such of you as believe and do good work that He will surely make them to succeed (the present rulers) in the earth even as He caused those who were before them to succeed (others); and that He will surely establish for them their religion which He hath approved for them, and will give them in exchange safety after their fear. They serve Me. They ascribe no thing as partner unto Me. Those who disbelieve henceforth, they are the miscreants." 
(Qoran 24:55, Pickthall Translation)

2. Read the Qoran and apply it to your life using your logic and invoke God to help you. Do not be afraid of using your logic to understand the Qoran.
3. Do good deeds that God orders, among them are helping family members, the poor, the orphan...

See the following verses:

"And serve Allah. Ascribe no thing as partner unto Him. (Show) kindness unto parents, and unto near kindred, and orphans, and the needy, and unto the neighbour who is of kin (unto you) and the neighbour who is not of kin, and the fellow-traveller and the wayfarer and (the slaves) whom your right hands possess. Lo! Allah loveth not such as are proud and boastful,"
(Qoran 4:36, Pickthall Translation)

"They ask thee, (O Muhammad), what they shall spend. Say: that which ye spend for good (must go) to parents and near kindred and orphans and the needy and the wayfarer. And whatsoever good ye do, lo! Allah is Aware of it."
(Qoran 2:215, Pickthall Translation)

I think the most important thing is that you should always use your logic and question everything including my post. If you lose your logic you lose everything! Reasoning and logic are 2 keys.

See the following verse:

"It is not for any soul to believe save by the permission of Allah. He hath set uncleanness upon those who have no sense."
(Qoran 10:100, Pickthall Translation)